# Randomizer game - two semantic errors

Tags: python

```
import random
print "This is a Coin War!"
coins_each = raw_input("How many coins for each player?:")
coins_each = int(coins_each)
player1 = coins_each
player2 = coins_each
possibilities = ["Heads", "Tails"]
count = 1
while player1 >= 0 and player2 >= 0:
    print "Round", count, "Player A:", player1, "Player B:", player2
    coin1 = random.choice(possibilities)
    coin2 = random.choice(possibilities)
    count = count + 1
    print "\tCoin A:", coin1
    print "\tCoin B:", coin2
    if coin1 == coin2:
        player1 = player1+1
        player2 =player2-1
        print "Same ---> A wins"
        print ("")
    else:
        player1 = player1-1
        player2= player2+1
        print "Different--->B wins",
        print ("")
    if player1 == 0:
        print "Player B wins the game"
    if player2 == 0:
        print "Player A wins the game"
```

Right now, I'm hitting two roadblocks. The "Player A wins the game" is printing before the last round shows. And sometimes the game doesn't terminate when one hits zero - which I'm sure has something to do with my while loop.

Both errors can be seen here:
[image: image link]:

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change

```
while player1 >= 0 and player2 >= 0:
```

to

```
while player1 > 0 and player2 > 0:
```

since you want the loop to stop if either player1 == 0 or player2 == 0.

Comment: I've tried that and it leads to http://i.imgur.com/YmjJf2A.png The last round doesn't print.

Comment: You could print the last round after the loop, i.e., just add the print statement at the top of the while loop after the loop exits.

Comment: Ok. Gave that a try. http://i.imgur.com/Ky9IVk2.png The last round that's printed, always seems to be a reprint of the coins from the previous rounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the condition

```
while player1 > 0 and player2 > 0:
```

will help you exit when either player wins. Also you can display the count of coins with each player after you increment/decrement their values. So when the count is decreased, it'll show 0 at which case the conditions satisfy and you'll exit the loop. At this point of time there shouldn't be anymore rounds.